# How to pass kwargs with the same name as a positional argument of a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword-argument

I am trying to call a wrapper from SK-learn which passes its `**kwargs` to an inner function. Unfortunately, one of its positional arguments has the same name as one of the arguments I want to pass in the `**kwargs`. I can't figure out how to pass them properly.

Example:

```
# This is a stand-in for a library function. I can't modify its behaviour.
def outer_function(fn, a, **kwargs):
    # do something entirely unrelated with a
    fn(**kwargs)

def expects_parameter_a(a):
    print(a)

def expects_parameter_b(b):
    print(b)

outer_function(expects_parameter_b, a=10, b=20) # this works as expected.
> 20

outer_function(expects_parameter_a, a=10, a=20) # this doesn't work.
outer_function(expects_parameter_a, a=10, kwargs={"a": 20}) # this doesn't work.
outer_function(expects_parameter_a, a=10, **{"a": 20}) # this doesn't work.
```

Comment: "I am trying to call a wrapper from SK-learn" - what wrapper is this?

Comment: How does your code know whether it needs to pass on ``a``? It would be incorrect to pass on ``a`` to ``expects_parameter_b``. Does ``outer_function`` use the kwargs at all? Why does ``outer_function`` do something *entirely unrelated*?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica specifically `GridSearchCV.fit` which has a `groups` argument, while my inner model also needs a `groups` argument in its `fit` method.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi it's not entirely unrelated. It just uses the argument and does not pass it into the inner method. It's not really relevant for the question I don't think. It just matters that the argument exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make those parameters "first level" arguments; instead, accept a dict of arguments you're going to pass on to `fn`:

```
def outer_function(fn, a, fn_kwargs):
    # do something entirely unrelated with a
    fn(**fn_kwargs)

outer_function(expects_parameter_a, a=10, fn_kwargs={"a": 20})
```

This could really be simplified and generalised to this:

```
from functools import partial

def outer_function(fn, a):
    ...
    fn()

outer_function(partial(expects_parameter_a, a=20))
# or:
outer_function(lambda: expects_parameter_a(a=20))
```

In other words, don't let `outer_function` worry about passing on the parameters at all, simply pass in a callable that already has all necessary parameters bound to it.

Comment: Sadly the `outer_function` is from a library, so its API is out of my control. The simplified suggestion is very useful though. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the arguments to the inner function using [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial), and pass `a` to `outer_function` separately:

```
outer_function(partial(expects_parameter_b, b=20), a=10)
outer_function(partial(expects_parameter_a, a=10), a=20)
```

This avoids passing arguments from `outer_function` to the inner function, and thus circumvents any conflicts. Note that `outer_function` does not need to be modified for this to work.

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this

```
def f1(*args, **kwargs):
    print("args   : ", args)
    print("kwargs : ", kwargs)

f1()
f1(1, 2)
f1(a=100, b=200)
f1(1, a=100)
f1(1, 2, a=100, b=200)
```

Output...

```
args   :  ()
kwargs :  {}
args   :  (1, 2)
kwargs :  {}
args   :  ()
kwargs :  {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
args   :  (1,)
kwargs :  {'a': 100}
args   :  (1, 2)
kwargs :  {'a': 100, 'b': 200}
```