# How to feed a dictionary as parameters to a function with a mix of positional and named arguments?

Tags: python

Given a dictionary `params={'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3}` I want to pass them to a function `foo`:

```
def foo(a, b, c=None, d=None):
   pass
```

Something as simple as `foo(**params)` would complain about mixing positional and named arguments.

There is an ugly way:

```
a = params['a']
b = params['b']
del params['a']
del params['b']
foo(a, b, **params)
```

But what I am ideally looking for is something like:

```
def separate(params:  Dict, func: Callable) -> List[Any], Dict[str, Any]:
   ...


args, kwargs = separate(params, foo)
foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a nice way to do it or should I rely on `inspect` and implement the `separate` function myself here?

[related questions don't address the issue: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61746117/how-to-pass-kwargs-with-the-same-name-as-a-positional-argument-of-a-function), [2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932052/neatly-pass-positional-arguments-as-args-and-optional-arguments-as-kwargs-from-a)

Comment: "foo(**params) would complain about mixing positional and named arguments." - it does not complain

Comment: Do you have some linter or IDE that is complaining about a mix? The runtime will not care; `foo(**params)` will work fine, unless `foo` is not defined the way you show in the question.

Comment: right. it was complaining at foo(a, **params) I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
import inspect
from typing import Dict, Callable, List, Any

def separate(params: Dict, func: Callable) -> List[Any], Dict[str, Any]:
    sig = inspect.signature(func)
    args = []
    kwargs = {}
    for name, param in sig.parameters.items():
        if name in params:
            if param.kind == param.POSITIONAL_OR_KEYWORD:
                args.append(params[name])
            elif param.kind == param.KEYWORD_ONLY:
                kwargs[name] = params[name]
    return args, kwargs
```

If there is anything you can't understand from the code comment below!